# Hint text is not being removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/udit_sharma/GFknc/

I have created this fiddle. which have a input box and it has hint-Text. When i am focused in this input box it's hint-Text is being cleared properly. and when i focused-out of this input box hint-Text is being showed again if there is nothing entered by user.

But there is an issue .let say you are focused in input-box and clicked on another tab in the browser now if you comeback to this fiddle again notice that hint-Text is being shown while it was empty while leaving this page. and also its not clearing this while clicking in and out of the input box. ?

So the issue i found is when i click on another tab onblur is not being called so that variable "valueChanged"  is not being set to false. So while focusing again it is not clearing the default hint-Text value.

So i am not getting why onBlur is not being called. If any one have clue about this, please tell or is there any other way to do this functionality ?

Comment: i couldn't reproduce your problem...

Comment: well i could at least on chrome

Comment: On my browser it is working absolutly fine,, which browser are you using

Comment: On a side note, why not use placeholder and use a polyfill to make it work in older browsers?  see http://html5please.com/ for the input[placeholder] polyfill

Comment: worked perfectly for me. have you tried window.onblur and window.onfocus? might help you.

Comment: i am using chromimum-17.0.963.65

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<input type="text" name="placeHolder" placeholder="hy i'm a place holder" />
```

it's an html5 attribute so, you may add the `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the top of your html file.

Comment: This works but only on web browsers (internet explorer is not one of them).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Chrome is firing onblur for the textbox twice. I was able to solve this by making the blur event a named function and binding blur during focus `addOptionInputEle.off('blur').on('blur', onAddOptionBlur);`. Then, within onAddOptionBlur I made a loop to unbind all instances of blur handlers.

```
while(addOptionInputEle.data('events').blur)
{
    addOptionInputEle.off('blur');
}
```

note: not tested in anything other than chrome.